# Python: append kmean.labels_ to Numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, append, k-means

The size of two `Numpy` array are:

```
(406, 278)
(406,)
```

however, error occurred while appending `Numpy` array:

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

code:

```
y = numpy.array(kmeans.labels_,copy=True)
x = numpy.append(x, y, axis=1); #error
x = numpy.append(x, y, axis=0); #error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you are trying to append a 1d array to a 2d array with an axis parameter, and according to docs:

> When `axis` is specified, `values` must have the correct shape.

You need to reshape `y` to a 2d array firstly:

Both of these two methods should work:

```
np.append(x, y[None, :], axis=0)
np.append(x, y.reshape(1,-1), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [numpy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) ,

> When axis is specified, values must have the correct shape.

So if you want to append the vector `y = [0 1 2]` to the matrix `x = [[0, 0],[1, 1],[2, 2]]` with `axis=1`, first you need to turn `y` into a matrix form, and then transpose it:

```
x = numpy.zeros((406,278))
y = numpy.zeros((406,))
x = numpy.append(x, numpy.transpose([y]), axis=1);
print(x.shape)   # gives (406,279)
```